# How save JS event changes into browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on an eCommerce website. I have this js code that when i pressed the add to cart button. The button will change into added if successfully added to the cart. The problem is when i pressed that add cart button then Visit another page, and when i press the back button on the browser. the page was loaded before the click event on js happens. so the button is still "add to cart". not "Added". but when i refresh the page. Everything works fine.

is it possible to save event changes into the browser history? or is there any correct method on achieving this?

Comment: You should definetly store it in `localStorage`. If you really want to modify the url, use `location.history.pushState`

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow to save key/value pairs in a web browser.

The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

The localStorage property is read-only.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var Val = localStorage.getItem("AddCartEvent");
      if(Val=="1"){
         $("#AddCart").prop("disabled",true);
         $("#AddCart").html("NO");
      }
      $("#AddCart").on("click",function(){
        var Status=$(this).val();
        if(Status=="0"){
          localStorage.setItem("AddCartEvent","1" );
          $(this).val("0");
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }
        else{
          localStorage.setItem("AddCartEvent","0" );
          $(this).val("1");
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
        }
      });
    });
```